# What type of Facebook Page for a Publication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A local magazine (my client) wants to have a Facebook page, in which of the Page Categories does a publication fit?

surly in "Brand, product, or organization" but sadly there is no "publication" in the dropdown

Comment: ended up making a generic "brand" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1. Local Business
2. Brand, Product or Organization
3. Artist, Band or public figure.

I would choose 2, brand, product or organization.
Once you create the page, you need to get 25 fans before you can reserve a custom URLfor it" `www.facebook.com/mypublication/`

The page is like a profile, but has fans instead of friends.  It also has page specific settings for wall and privacy.

After you create your page you can use an app, like Facebook custom FMBL page to create custom components or tabs for it.  With that you will use the Facebook API.